# Find similar entries in database / avoid duplicate entries (PHP, MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with different words as entries. For example

```
ID | words
 1 | dog cat mouse elephant bird
 2 | man woman child Boy girl 
 3 | red green blue yellow black white grey
```

I'm looking for a function or script to find similar entries in my database. For example

```
$str = "grey white black yellow purple";
-> similar to ID 3, ~ 80% 

$str = "snake dog elephant rabbit";
-> similar to ID 1, ~ 10% 

$str = "Rom London Berlin Paris";
-> similar to nothing, ~0%
```

How can I check with PHP/MySQL if there is an similar entrie?

I don't want to have duplicate content in my database.
I donw't want to have "car bike plane train" in one row and "bike plane train car" in another row...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For what you're trying to achieve, it sounds like your database design is not the best. Is there any reason "bike", "plane", "train" and "car" can't each be in their own column? Or if the number of words isn't static, can they be in their own row with an ID for each set?

Comment: This is pretty broad - it might be useful to get an idea of the string created? Is it user-selected via a form or something? Initial thoughts: you'd have to find some way to categorise the words; e.g: dog -> animal, red -> colour etc.

Comment: Look into "natural language processing", i.e. in a search engine

Comment: Do you need that percentage, or would a yes/no - i.e. there is a row with those words in some order be enough?

Comment: Look at MySQL's `full text searching` feature.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird:a yes/no would be enough. I don't Need the percentage.